# How was $T(N)$ derived for this function?

Tags: asymptotics

[image]

I’m struggling to understand how $T(N)=C_1 \times N + C_2$ was derived

Assuming $C_1$ refers to `l <- 0`, and $C_2$ refers to `return l`

Shouldn’t it total $T(N)= C_1 + (N + 1) + N + C_2$, which simplifies to $T(N)= C_1 + 2N + 1 + C_2$ ?

Comment: $c_1$ accounts for the time expended during each iteration of the `while` loop. Namely, the `l<-l+1`, the check `A[l]!=NULL` and any other overhead of the whole iteration, like moving back to the beginning of the loop, for example. The $c_2$ accounts for the `l<-0`, the `return l` and any other operations involved with calling the function, like allocating information in a call stack, for example. Note that the $c_1$ and the $N$ get multiplied the cost $c_1$ occurs in each of the $N$ iterations. The [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) is being applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants that concern several instructions:

- $C_2$ corresponds to instructions executed only **once** `l <- 0`, the last executed test of `while(A[l]!=NULL)` and `return l`
- $C_1$ corresponds to instructions executed several times: each test of `while(A[l]!=NULL)` but the last, and `l<-l+1`. Those are executed a total of $N$ times.

We indeed get $T(N) = C_1\times N + C_2$.